# Returning a hyperlink in an Ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember component called `alert-message` which returns a more user-friendly error message for validation purposes. One of the error messages contains an ID (which I've hardcoded here)- I'd like to turn the ID into a hyperlink and display it in the message.

I understand using the str.link() method simply creates a string representing the code for an HTML link element.

What I currently have renders this: 
`"Cannot update this item with <a href="/items/31010-2001-20311">31010-2001-20311</a>."`

How do I turn the generated html into an actual link? Or is this something I should be doing in the handlebars piece instead?

In my component template I render:
`{{alert-message errorMessage= errorMessage}}`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Component.extend({
      errorMessage: function () {
        const status = this.getWithDefault('status', '');
          if (status === '409') {
            var id = 31010-2001-20311;
            var idLink = id.link('/items/31010-2001-20311');
            return `Cannot update this item with ${idLink}.`;
            }
        {
          return status;
        }
      }.property('status')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I should deal with this (the displaying of the actual link) in the handlebars template/view rather than in the component.

To solve this, I'm adding a `specificError` property to the component which is set to false by default. In my errorMessage validations, if an error message matching this specific case occurs, specificError is toggled to true with `this.toggleProperty('specificError')`

In my handlebars template I'll check whether such error exists, and display the error there.